# PHP Submit multiple questions in a quiz

Tags: php, html

I would like to create a html quiz with a dynamic number of questions and each question has a dynamic number of answers.  My goal is to submit all of the questions when the quiz is completed.  What changes to my HMTL do I need to make and what php do I use to get the array?

HTML

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">  
  <div class="questions">
    <strong class="white">Question 1</strong>
    <input name="questions[]" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="a"> <label>answer 1</label><br>
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="b"> <label>answer 2</label><br>    
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="c"> <label>answer 3</label><br>
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="d"> <label>answer 4</label><br>   
  </div>
  <div class="questions">
    <strong class="white">Question 2</strong>
    <input name="questions[]" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="a"> <label>answer 1</label><br>
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="b"> <label>answer 2</label><br>    
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="c"> <label>answer 3</label><br>
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="d"> <label>answer 4</label><br>   
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="e"> <label>answer 5</label><br> 
    <input name="answers[]" type="checkbox" value="f"> <label>answer 6</label><br> 
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$questionID = $_POST['questions'];
$answers = $_POST['answers'];
foreach( $questionID as $i => $qid ) {
   echo "The question id is ".$qid." and selected answer(s) is ".$answers[$i]. "<br>";
}
```

I believe one of my html problems has to do with the answers are named the same for both questions.  Another php problem is which answer(s) were selected.  I do not want to use AJAX as that causes more load on the server and I use JS for a quiz timer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I need the number of questions and the number of answers to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
$questionAnswers = array('question1'=>array('answer1','answer2','answer3','answer4'));
$questionText = array('question1'=>'Question 1');
```

Displaying the form:

```
<form>
    <?php foreach($questionAnswers as $q => $answers)
          {
            echo '<div class="questions"><strong class="white">'.$questionText[$q].'</strong>'

            for($i = 0; $i < count($answers); $i++)
            {
              echo '<input name="'.$q.'[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'"> <label>'.$answers[$i].'</label><br>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
          }
    ?>
</form>
```

Processing submission:

```
$foreach($questionAnswers as $q => $answers)
{
  $userAnswers = isset($_REQUEST[$q]) ? $_REQUEST[$q] : array();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the number of the question in the input name attribute, e.g.:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">  
  <div class="questions">
    <strong class="white">Question 1</strong>
    <input name="questions" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="answers[1]" type="checkbox" value="a"> <label>answer 1</label><br>
    <input name="answers[1]" type="checkbox" value="b"> <label>answer 2</label><br>    
    <input name="answers[1]" type="checkbox" value="c"> <label>answer 3</label><br>
    <input name="answers[1]" type="checkbox" value="d"> <label>answer 4</label><br>   
  </div>
  <div class="questions">
    <strong class="white">Question 2</strong>
    <input name="questions" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input name="answers[2]" type="checkbox" value="a"> <label>answer 1</label><br>
    <input name="answers[2]" type="checkbox" value="b"> <label>answer 2</label><br>    
    <input name="answers[2]" type="checkbox" value="c"> <label>answer 3</label><br>
    <input name="answers[2]" type="checkbox" value="d"> <label>answer 4</label><br>   
    <input name="answers[2]" type="checkbox" value="e"> <label>answer 5</label><br> 
    <input name="answers[2]" type="checkbox" value="f"> <label>answer 6</label><br> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Then when you get a $_POST it will be like:

answers[1] = 'a',
   answers[2] = 'b' ....